# Is possible to "choose" the ID field like the TEXT one?

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I have a situation where my json array will contain both `id` and `text`, however I would like to use `full_name` field as `id`, are there any option to do it?

Here is an example on the documentation:

```
    $(".select2-cat-color").select2({
        data:function() { return { text:'tag', results: data }; },
        formatSelection: format,
        formatResult: format
    });
```

I can't find any documentation about `id`, so I was looking for some hacks to achieve it.

**Update 1:**
Notice I want to use a different id for returned JSON data, like:

```
[{ id: 1, text: 'something', full_name: 'something else'},...]
```

I would like to be able to use as `id` the `full_name` field, so that the value sent when I submit the form, will be `full_name` content, not `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it by myself in the documentation, the parameter `id` which is available for the object passed to `select2` method (the select2 options) takes a function which takes the selected object as a parameter.

I can return whatever I want as `id`, that's perfect.